# Could not parse the remainder: '(song)' from 'playlist.songs.add(song)'

Tags: python, html, django, button

Here are my Playlist & Song model :

## models.py

```
class Song(models.Model):
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False,default='')
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    @property
    def playlist_id(self):
        return self.id
```

Here is my template :

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Add to playlist<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    {% for playlist in all_playlists %}
    <li><button onclick="{{playlist.songs.add(song)}}">{{playlist.name}}</button></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the drop down button 'Add to playlist', it shows a drop down list of playlists. But what I want is when the user clicks on the playlists, the song should get added to the songs field of the playlist. For that purpose, I created a button with  action = `playlists.songs.add(song)`.When I render it, it returned this error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '(song)' from
>   'playlist.songs.add(song)'

So I fired up django shell and then typed the same thing, it worked in the shell but not in the template. Here is my shell log.

```
In [1]: from music.models import Song, Playlist

In [2]: s = Song.objects.get(pk=2)

In [3]: p1 = Playlist.objects.get(pk=2)

In [4]: p1.songs.add(s)

In [5]: p1.songs.all()
Out[5]: [<Song: Shape of you>]
```

Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Code written for `onclick` event will be called on the client side and you cannot execute python in browser. You can write javascript to send an HTTP request to your server to add a song to playlist or you can use django forms.

Comment: How can I do this in django?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the solutions.

1. Create a django [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) with an appropriate field for multiple choice. Insert it in your template within form tag with `POST` method.
2. Create a url and view to handle this `POST` request. You can write code to add song to playlist in this view. Then re-render your template.